# I extended an Application and I need data to NOT persists after application is closed

Tags: android

It is simple I guess.

I have a User and some other objects that I need to use along many activities of my application, so I decided to create a class and extend Application to make these objects "globals", e.g. after the user does the login, I have the user object along all my activities to use.

The problem is that after the application is closed the data is not lost/reseted. So when I open my app again, it does not ask for me to do my login again. So I need to somehow close the other Application. How do I do it?

A palliative solution I found is to set the variables to `null` when `backPressed` is called from `MainActivity` (and my application is closed), but I know it is not right, must have a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Reference counting. Once you have Application instance, so any activities can call methods on it. Define 2 synchronized methods like onResumeActivity() and onPauseActivity() and call them from all activities. You can use Handler to postpone message once onPauseActivity has been called. Once message is delivered - null reference your data.

Comment: Your `backPressed` method is a fairly common solution to this problem. If you're confident that pressing the Back button from `MainActivity` means that your app is exiting, then the simplest solution is to reset your data at that point.